# Какие есть свободные библиотеки которые генерируют обычные трёхмерные объекты?

Tags: графика, 3d, поиск-библиотек

Чайники, различные сферы и т.д. Нужны функции, задаешь параметры, например, сферы, радиус, количество сегментов и т.д., и на выходе возвращаются массивы с координатами и индексами. Мне не нужны OpenGL DirectX это не библиотеки.

Comment: Генерируют чайники? о_О

Comment: DirectX генерирует чайники, различные сферы и т.д. но он не очень свободный. OpenGl свободный, но не уверен, что там есть чайник

Comment: Что такое "обычные трехмерные объекты", что такое "генерируют"? Обычно низкоуровневые API таким вообще не занимаются. Их дело - рисовать треугольники. Для OpenGL чайники бюли в GLU или GLUT, кажется. Библиотек-оберток полно, и вы сами можете написать мини-библиотечку с кубами, торами и сферами. В общем, вопрос неясен.

Comment: @ArtemRachmaninov не распаляйтесь пожалуйста, пользы это не принесет. Уточните лучше что за объекты вам нужны, и чем, например, не подойдет десяток объектов сохраненных из Blender которые вы бы просто масштабировали?

Answer (score 1):

https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/GLUT

> OpenGL Utility Toolkit (GLUT) — библиотека утилит для приложений под OpenGL, которая в основном отвечает за системный уровень операций ввода-вывода при работе с операционной системой. Из функций можно привести следующие: создание окна, управление окном, мониторинг за вводом с клавиатуры и событий мыши. Она также включает функции для рисования ряда геометрических примитивов: куб, сфера, [чайник](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A7%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA_%D0%AE%D1%82%D0%B0). GLUT даже включает возможность создания несложных всплывающих меню.

https://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/

PS: Случайно наткнулся на статью в википедии и по чайнику вспомнил этот вопрос)))